# Modals in React applications

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I would like to ask you how you create and manage modals in your React applications. I saw the solution when modals are handled using Redux.For example you dispatch the modal key and props into the state and after display the modal using a key. The minos of this approach is that when you need to pass some function into modal as a prop, redux warns you that functions can't be serialized and that's why it is no recommended approach. Some developers prefer using emitters to resolve this redux issue or something else.

What is your favorite solution? I would be thankful for your recommendations